# pygame window does not show caption on ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ubuntu, pygame

I am trying to run this on ubuntu 20.04:

```
pygame.init()
win_size = (800, 500)
win = pygame.display.set_mode(win_size, 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption("Alpha")
```

It runs but it does not show the caption.

where have i gone wrong ?

Comment: Call `pygame.event.pump()` after setting the caption.

Comment: Tried and it didn't work.

Comment: I think you have to call `pygame.init()` first.

Comment: @Roadowl A45 already called `pygame.init()`

Answer (score 0):

On some systems, the caption won't change unless you set it before creating the display. Put `pygame.display.set_caption("Alpha")` before `pygame.display.set_mode(win_size, 0, 32)` and see if that fixes the problem.